# Getting access to ui elements in different fxml file

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have a FXML-application with a main.fxml, which includes two other fxml files. Each of these fxml files has its own controller class.

My question is, of how to get access to objects from a specific controller, although these objects are defined on another fxml file.

The following code is just a minimal example. I thought it was a good idea to split ui elements in different fxml files, because they are getting larger and larger.

My main fxml:

```
<VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="MainController">
   <fx:include fx:id="top" source="top.fxml"/>
   <fx:include fx:id="bottom" source="bottom.fxml"/>
</VBox>
```

top.fxml:

```
<VBox fx:id="vbox" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="ControllerTop">
  <children>
    <Button fx:id="topbtn" onAction="#printOutput" text="OK" />
  </children>
</VBox>
```

bottom.fxml

```
<VBox fx:id="vbox" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="ControllerBottom">
  <children>
    <Button fx:id="bottombtn" onAction="#printOutput" text="OK" />
  </children>
</VBox>
```

For top.fxml i have created this controller class:

```
public class ControllerTop {
    @FXML public Button topbtn;
    @FXML public Button bottombtn;

    @FXML
    public void printOutput() {
        System.out.println("Hello from top button");
        topbtn.setDisable(true); //OK!
        bottombtn.setDisable(false); //Failed
    }
}
```

Of course bottombtn is defined in bottom.fxml and has its own controller. The problem is, that bottombtn of printOut() of this ControllerTop results in a NullPointerException. So i need help by accessing objects in a nice and smart way.

Thanks

Comment: You can inject the controllers of `fx:include`d files. See the [Nested Controllers](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers) section of _Introduction to FXML_.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advice. But this ends up in "cyclic references", because ControlerTop should deactivate bottombtn and ControllerBottom should deactivate topbtn.

Comment: Using a proper model or communicating via `MainController` would fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in main controller:

```
public class MainController {
/**
 * var name has to be topController
 */
public TopController topController;
/**
 * var name has to be bottomController
 */
public BottomController bottomController;

public void initialize(){
    Button topbtn=topController.topbtn;
    Button bottombtn=bottomController.bottombtn;
    topbtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Hello from top button");
            topbtn.setDisable(true); //OK!
            bottombtn.setDisable(false); //Failed
        }
    });

}
}
```

bottom.fxml:

```
    <VBox fx:id="vbox" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="BottomController">
  <children>
    <Button fx:id="bottombtn" text="OK" />
  </children>
</VBox>
```

top.fxml:

```
 <VBox fx:id="vbox" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="TopController">
  <children>
    <Button fx:id="topbtn" text="OK" />
  </children>
</VBox>
```

and in class TopController and BottomController set  `@FXML public Button **btnName**;`

BottomController:

```
public class BottomController {    
    public Button bottombtn;
}
```

TopController:

```
public class TopController {
    public Button topbtn;
}
```

Another option it to use `initialize` at `MainController`  to set the value of `bottombtn` in topController